# Array Reverse XOR Swap is broken when condensed

Tags: java, arrays, bitwise-xor

I had a for-loop to reverse an array using the classic XOR swap method. I tried condensing the code into a single expression, but for some reason it breaks. Can someone explain what's going on here?

Firstly, assume the `char[] s` contains the characters of the word `"hello"`.

This is the classic algorithm, and it works just fine.

```
int len = s.length;
for (int i = 0; i < len / 2; i++){
    s[i]        ^= s[len-i-1];
    s[len-i-1]  ^= s[i];
    s[i]        ^= s[len-i-1];
}
```

Noticing that the result of the first line is the input on the second line, I just substituted it down, like so:

```
int len = s.length;
for (int i = 0; i < len / 2; i++){
    s[len-i-1]  ^= (s[i] ^= s[len-i-1]);
    s[i]        ^= s[len-i-1];
}
```

That, too, works just fine. But, you can see again that the output of the first line is used as the input of the second line. So I just did it again, like so:

```
int len = s.length;
for (int i = 0; i < len / 2; i++){
    s[i] ^= (s[len-i-1]  ^= (s[i] ^= s[len-i-1]));
}
```

I parenthesized it to make the order in which the operations are done more clear. But the moment you do this a second time, the results are weird. This is the array after the code directly above executes:
`["\u0000","\u0000","l","e","h"]`

The first half of the chars got nullified. I'm assuming this is due to the XOR operation happening on the same thing twice because `(a ^ a) = 0`, but I'm not sure how that could be happening. Why are only half of the chars being set to 0? Why specifically the second half? Is it a compiler optimization that's breaking things? There are a lot of questions about this. If someone could provide some sort of breakdown of what's actually happening here, that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with the order in which java evaluates expressions and writes to memory. Basically, the second XOR that you're doing is reading the value before java got around to writing to memory. Thus, this method of a one line XOR swap is not possible. Fear not, however, because there is a way easier one:
`a=a^b^(b=a);`
This works because the expression `(b=a)` resonates with `a`, but does not set the value of `b` to `a` until `a` is set to `a^b^(resonance of b=a)`
It's a little weird to think about the order these operations happen in, but hopefully this steers you the right way.